# pytest: How can you use mocker.patch on a function that is defined inside of a test?

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I have a pytest file called `test_util` that looks like this:

```
import pytest

class TestUtil:
    def test_split_kwargs(self, mocker):
        def testfunction_extra(e='5',f='6'):
            return e+f
        mocker.patch(...)
```

I would like to use the `assert_has_calls` method on my `testfunction_extra` function, but I'm not sure what to put into my `mocker.patch` statement. I have already tried

```
mocker.patch(__name__ + '.TestUtil.test_split_kwargs.testfunction_extra')
```

but this returns the error `AttributeError: <function TestUtil.test_split_kwargs at 0x7fce6612e790> does not have the attribute 'testfunction_extra'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't patch local variables, only global names and attributes of objects you have a reference to. But good news! You don't *need* to patch this, because you have a reference to the function right there to wrap in a `Mock` object yourself.

```
import unittest.mock


class TestUtil:
    def test_split_kwargs(self):
        def _(e='5', f='6'):
            return e + f

        testfunction_extra = unittest.mock.Mock(wraps=_)
        ...
```

You could even use a decorator for this, starting in Python 3.9:

```
class TestUtil:
    def test_split_kwargs(self):
        @lambda f: unittest.mock.Mock(wraps=f)
        def testfunction_extra(e='5', f='6'): 
            return e + f

        ...
```